# How to make my widgets not to appear in center

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I have all my widgets placed in center (except the one on the left side, 'cauz i want it to be there only), both in a grid and horizontal layout. Let me show you :

[image: all widgets in the centre]

I Want them to be placed like this in the image below, and not all the widgets in the center like the image above  :

[image: all widgets at corner and one at center]

As you can see, the top one's are in corners, and the one rectangle in the middle is at the center. I want them to be placed wherever i want, whether in the between or in the corner, but at the same time, not losing my grids and spacing added as when you stretch this horizontally/vertically it will add up more/less space between the widgets. As you can see yourself by stretching the app.

**Here's my code :**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QFrame
from PySide2.QtCore import QRect

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 80, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("test app")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff; border")

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.setFixedWidth(260)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.994, y1:0.527, x2:0.999682, y2:0.005, stop:0 rgba(246, 246, 246, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 248, 248, 255));")

        lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setFixedWidth(310)
        lineedit.setFixedHeight(30)
        lineedit.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: #ffffff; 
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-color: rgb(200, 200, 200); 
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 4;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        color: rgb(50,50,50);
        font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular;
        font-size: 12px;
        """)
        f = lineedit.font()
        f.setLetterSpacing(QtGui.QFont.PercentageSpacing, 100)
        lineedit.setFont(f)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("New Product")
        button.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete Product")
        button1.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button1.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button1.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next product")
        button2.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button2.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        widget.setFixedSize(180, 180)
        widget.setStyleSheet("""background-color: rgb(200, 255, 250)""")

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        right_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        glay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(right_container)
        glay.addWidget(lineedit, 0, 0)
        glay.addWidget(widget, 1, 0)
        glay.addWidget(button, 2, 0)

        glay.addWidget(button1, 2, 1)

        glay.addWidget(button2, 0, 1)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay.addWidget(label)
        hlay.addWidget(right_container)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried many things, but ended up with errors. I just ran out of logic, about how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance...

**Edit 1:**
I tried both of these things that was suggested in comments :

1) Adding `glay.addWidget(lineedit, 0, 0, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)`. It's producing the same result even after applying the changes.

2) Using a QVBoxLayout isn't helpful though. There is something that is not allowing me to add the widgets at the rectangle i draw below. Because i can't add widgets at the rectangle side. (See the image below...)

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want them to be placed wherever i want"? It could help if you could show us an example image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @musicamante Oh sorry for this. The example image is the second one. I want to achieve that. And what I meant by placing the widgets wherever I want is that I can either place them at the corner or at the center. I just want to get rid of all the widgets from the centre. As you can see in the first image. All the widgets under the grid are in center. I want the image 2 as the result.

Comment: Well, giving you a specific answer is difficult, as it really depends on the widgets that you add to the layout. For example, the label at the center has a fixed size, so it will never be resized. What you want to achieve could be done in different ways. You could use the alignment argument for corner widgets (for example `glay.addWidget(lineedit, 0, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)`). Or you could use nested layouts (use a VBox instead of a Grid for `glay`, add a QHBoxLayout for the top widgets, and use a `addStretch()` before adding the widget to the right). And so on...

Comment: Please see my edit 1 in the answer. @musicamante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QGridLayout::setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch)
>
> Sets the stretch factor of column column to stretch. The first column is number 0.

---

> void QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)
>
> Sets the stretch factor of row row to stretch. The first row is number 0.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 80, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("test app")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff; border")

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.setFixedWidth(260)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.994, y1:0.527, x2:0.999682, y2:0.005, stop:0 rgba(246, 246, 246, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 248, 248, 255));")

        lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setFixedWidth(310)
        lineedit.setFixedHeight(30)
        lineedit.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: #ffffff; 
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-color: rgb(200, 200, 200); 
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 4;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        color: rgb(50,50,50);
        font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular;
        font-size: 12px;
        """)
        f = lineedit.font()
        f.setLetterSpacing(QtGui.QFont.PercentageSpacing, 100)
        lineedit.setFont(f)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("New Product")
        button.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete Product")
        button1.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button1.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button1.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next product")
        button2.setFixedSize(110, 28)
        button2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button2.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
        background-color: #474767;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border-radius: 3;
        font-family: Source Sans Pro SemiBold;
        }
        QPushButton:hover{
        background-color: #474757;
        }
        """)

        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
#        widget.setFixedSize(180, 180)
        widget.setMinimumHeight(180)                                           # +++

        widget.setStyleSheet("""background-color: rgb(200, 255, 250)""")

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        right_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        glay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(right_container)
        glay.addWidget(lineedit, 0, 0)
        glay.addWidget(button2, 0, 2)
        
        glay.addWidget(widget, 2, 0, 1, 3)                              # 2
        
        glay.addWidget(button, 4, 0)                                    # 4
        glay.addWidget(button1, 4, 2)
      
        glay.setColumnStretch(1, 1)                                     # setColumnStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(1, 1)                                        # setRowStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(2, 2)                                        # setRowStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(3, 1)                                        # setRowStretch
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay.addWidget(label)
        hlay.addWidget(right_container)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: But can you explain me what does `glay.addWidget(widget, 2, 0, 1, 3)` does? Also why you wrote ` .setRowStretch` 3 times with different values? I can't understand. Can you please explain me this? @S-Nick

Comment: I am a beginner in Pyqt, and trying to slowly learn everything. Your help is Highly appreciated.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi  see  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2

Comment: Thanks! but i just want to ask a question. I am still unable to understand what those two values do here in `setRowStretch(3, 1)` and in column? When i put any arbitrary number in place of 3 & 1, then some works and gives the same output while some acts weird.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi see  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setRowStretch